# people picker. It doesn't shows any AD users!

Tags: powershell, people-picker

I have created a BCS instance successfully but when I try to search for a user or group to grant permissions or add an administrator for this instance,the people picker can't find users from Active Directory?

I'm looking to do that with a powershell script.  Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Which one you are using sharepoint foundation or SharePoint server? If your are using sharepoint foundation we can not pick the employees from AD.

Comment: I use sharepoint server 2013,I cant create site collection with central admin cause people picker not work cant look for first admin for exemple...